Отключить автозапуск терминала и файлового менеджера archlinux
Archlinux со средой рабочего стола xfce4. При старте нового сеанса происходит автозапуск нескольких окон терминала и нескольких окон файлового менеджера.
Не понимаю, как это отключить.

На скриншоте настройки автостарта приложений,там ни того, ни другого нет.
Файлов конфигураций автозапуска тоже, вроде бы, нет.

Xfce#Autostart, обратите внимание на строчку Alternatively, add the commands you wish to run (including setting environment variables) to xinitrc (or xprofile when a display manager is being used). 
